# How to get highest value from a table field

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("dejavu");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$consulta_año_emision = "SELECT `año_emision` FROM `serie` ORDER BY `año_emision` DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultado_año_emision = mysql_query($consulta_año_emision); 
?>  

<select>
<?php 
    $año_actual = date("Y");
    for($año = $resultado_año_emision['año_emision']; $año <= $año_actual; $año++){ ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $año; ?>"><?php echo $año; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

What i'm trying to acomplish is a select that contains all the years between this year (2013), and the lowest year saved in the field 'año_emision' on my database.
What that's returning is all numbers between 1 and 2013, clearly not what I need. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: don't you want to just do a BETWEEN with a sub select of MIN on your first parameter and your current year as the second parameter? e.g SELECT * FROM table WHERE year BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(year) FROM another_table) AND $max_year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not done mysql_fetch_assoc. need to do  that

```
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_año_emision);
```

after this line

```
   $resultado_año_emision = mysql_query($consulta_año_emision); 
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado_año_emision);
```

then in for loop  use like this

```
 for($año = $result['año_emision']; $año <= $año_actual; $año++)
```

Note: mysql_* function are deprecated. try to use mysqli or PDO

Comment: I just tryied this but now i'm just getting 2013, no other value. EDIT: Nevermind, i got it, the DESC was wrong, I was trying to loop from 2013 to 2013 so thats why it only showed that one value, thanks dude!